# Semantic Differential Plot with Seaborn or Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is it possible to create a Semantic Differential Plot using Seaborn or Matplotlib? I could not find any hint, neither in the docs nor here.

A Semantic Differential Plot:

[image]

I was thinking about a Line Plot, but how do you map the second y-axis values?

If this is possible, how?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start by using an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) to store the attributes we'll plot:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np

dict = OrderedDict([('Wholesome', -2), ('Unique', -1), ('Established', 2), ('Traditional', 1)])
opposites = ('Exotic', 'Standard', 'New', 'Contemporary')
```

With this set up we can begin plotting. Let's define our figure and axis and make a simple scatter plot of our data:

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax1.plot(dict.values(), np.r_[:len(dict)], marker='o')
```

Okay, good, we're on our way. Next is to set the yticks to be the attributes we set in our dictionary (and while we're here let's ensure that we only use integers on the x-axis ticks).

```py
ax1.set_yticks(np.r_[:len(dict)])
ax1.set_yticklabels(dict.keys())
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

Next, let's set up the opposing attributes on the "other side" of the plot. Let's set up a twin axis to help us with this.

```py
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
```

Finally, let's label our twinned axis and ensure the paired attributes line up vertically.

```py
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
ax2.set_yticks(np.r_[:len(dict)])
ax2.set_yticklabels(opposites)
```

A call to `fig.tight_layout()` should ensure that the y-axis labels are visible. All this together gave me the following plot:

[image]